# Validação de Data Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Bom Dia ...

Gostaria de saber como posso validar uma data !
Onde a Data Final Não pode ser menor que a Data Inicial 
(dataFinal < dataInicial) com regex !

Comment: [I had a problem, and I thought "I know, I'll use regex!". Now I have two problems.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex, *definitivamente*, não é a ferramenta certa para resolver este problema.

Se queres comparar duas datas, então usa a struct [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.DateTime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Vou assumir que o input são duas strings, `s1` e `s2`, num formato válido.

```
var d1 = DateTime.Parse(s1)
var d2 = DateTime.Parse(s2)

d1 < d2
```

Se não se tiver a certeza que o formato das strings é valido, então deve-se usar [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Bom já consegui transforma de String para Datetime assim:

DateTime dataInicial = Convert.ToDateTime(dtIni.Text);

A dúvida é como não deixar continuar o código, se a data FINAL for menor que a Inicial

Comment: @LucianoRamos Como eu expliquei, basta usar o operador `<` para comparar duas instancias de `DateTime`.

Comment: Bom eu compreendi , porem o cód continua e traz uma tabela de registros, mas não quero que traga por conta que a data esta incorreta !

Comment: @LucianoRamos Nesse caso tens um bug no código. Tens de colocar uma *nova* pergunta (visto que esta já foi respondida), e de fornecer um [MCVE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para te podermos ajudar.

Comment: Hum entendi , muito Obrigado pela Ajuda ;-)

Comment: @LucianoRamos de nada, e bem vindo ao StackOverflow! Não te esqueças de [aceitar a resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).